# Read python output from another python script

Tags: python

I have two python files, one contains code which generates an output and the other needs to read it. The generation code is:

```
b=5
return b
```

The reading code is:

```
import os
c= os.system("test.py")
print (c)
```

When I run this, the output is 1. I don't understand why this isn't 5, any advise on how to fix this please?

Comment: When something runs, it returns whether the execution is a success or a failure. Test it out. raise some exception in test.py, and c would be equal to 0.

Comment: 1 is the termination status

Comment: `b = 5; return b` is not a legal Python program, because you can't have `return` outside of a function.

Comment: Are you required to use a file?  If not, perhaps a generator function would better do what you want.  You can find this technique by searching for the Python **yield** statement.

Comment: Use the `subprocess` module to run a program and read its output. Note that the output you read in is bytes that you can decode as text and then would need to parse as a number! If you don't need to run a separate program, just follow the other recommendations on importing modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all the code in your first file into a function.

```
#Fred.py
def frob():
    b=5
    return b
```

Then, you can import that function from any other Python file and see its return value.

```
#Barney.py
from Fred import frob
print frob()
#result: 5
```